# Not receiving random results from RAND() query on My SQLwith PHP

Tags: php, sql, random

I have a column with 4 rows. I use a query to return a random row but 95% of the time, I get the first row in the table. Very rarely do I get any other row than the first. 
Is there someething wrong with the way I am using this function in PHP?

```
//Array with the data to insert
$sql_array = array(
    'rightcolumn'    => 'rightcolumn',
);

// Create the SQL statement
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . rightcolumn . '
         ORDER BY RAND() = ' . 1;

 // Run the query 
 $result = $db->sql_query($sql);

 // $row should hold the data you selected
$row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);

// Be sure to free the result after a SELECT query                        
 $db->sql_freeresult($result);

// Show we got the result we were looking for
 echo $row['rightcolumn'];
```

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY RAND()` only, remove the `=1`

`ORDER BY RAND` is very inefficiency with a large table, 4 rows however is fine

Comment: Or change to `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: well that could be where that idea for `=1` comes from, so you would use both `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Comment: @starshine FYI, while answering your own question is fine when no one else does it, but if some one else does, its polite to give them due credit by marking their answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that `RAND()` returns values in `[0, 1)` range - the `RAND() = 1` expression always returns false.

So your `ORDER BY` clause can be represented as `ORDER BY false`, which has little sense.

Instead you must to order by a random value, ie:

```
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the explanation , helped me to understand it. Would give up vote, but I am a new user, apparently I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions by zerkms and Dagon above.

The statement should be:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . rightcolumn . '
        ORDER BY RAND()';
```